# Inverting selection in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, vector, features, select, select-by-location

I want to select the features that are not equal. So, I made a selection by the location where the geometric predicate is `equal` and then I thought to **invert** the selection.

Is there any way to invert the selection using PyQGIS?

My code:

```py
import processing

layer1 = processing.getObject('polygon1')
layer2 = processing.getObject('polygon2')

processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', layer2, layer1, u'equals', 0.005, 0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `layer2` is the layer holding selection, just use the [`invertSelection()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#af2c8db3639196641a7b79f6b6d2198ea) method:

```py
layer2.invertSelection()
```